# Foundation 5 topbar search in Safari

Tags: jquery, ios, safari, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I have some problem in Safari.

When I click to search icon, we have the drop down search input and when I start writing something, the top bar is broken.

But when the top bar is open and we write something in search, everything is OK.

I don't know why it happens, but in Chrome everything is OK.

http://joxi.ru/L213wwnSMdwQrX

http://joxi.ru/GrqVqqOI5LzZmz

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
            <ul class="title-area">
                <li class="name">
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logobrand"/></a>
                </li>

                <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
                <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>

                <li class="mob_search">
                    <span class="search"></span>

                    <div class="drop_search">
                        <div class=" collapse">
                            <div class="large-12 small-12 columns">
                                <form action="">
                                <button type="submit" class="search"></button>
                                <input type="search" placeholder="what are you looking for?">
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>

            </ul>

            <section class="top-bar-section">
                <!-- Right Nav Section -->
                <ul class="right">
                    <li class="divider"></li> .....
```

#### ----js----

```
$(".mob_search > .search").click(function(){
   $(".drop_search").toggle("slow");
});`
```